# How to extract and pass url parameter from complex url using Angular 6 router UrlMatcher matcher

Tags: angular, router

How to extract parameters from complex seo url for eg 
domain.com/product-samsung-tv-34.html 
Where 34 is the parameter to be pass to the respective component.

Answer (score 2):

The solution using Angular 6 matcher and regular expression 
Using UrlMatcher or matcher:

```
export const routes = [
  { matcher: YourMatcherLogic, component: ProductComponent },
```

YourMatcherLogic function

```
  // Url matcher for specific logic implementation and extract 
  parameter using regex.
  export function YourMatcherLogic(url: UrlSegment[]) {
    // Implement your logic to parse different url segments and extract value as parameters to pass to the component
    if ((url.length > 1 && url[1].path.endsWith('.html')) {
      let _id = extractIDFromEndsWithHTML(url[1].path);  // extractIDFromEndsWithHTML custom function that extracts id from urls 'hello/3.html' using regex
      // add id parameters
      url[1].parameters = {id: _id};
      return {
      consumed: url
    };
  } else {
    return null;
  }
```

}

In the component get the extracted parameters as

```
this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
  this.productId = params['id'];
});
```

Comment: Not the correct way to do it this will add a strange string to the path should not be used. For more info check the default implementation https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/828e5c1f79e53202be497fb57aa0b39bc3774300/packages/router/src/shared.ts

Answer (score 2):

For anyone having to deal with the UrlMatcher.

```
if (segments.length === 1) {
    return {
      consumed: segments, posParams: {
        id: segments[0]
      }
    };
  }
```

This is how the default implementation does it.

Comment: The result is of type UrlMatchResult, see https://angular.io/api/router/UrlMatchResult

Answer (score 0):

You can simply read about that in the Angular router doc  [Here](https://angular.io/guide/router#route-parameters-required-or-optional). Example in your component ngOnInt.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.heroes$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
        // (+) before `params.get()` turns the string into a number
        this.selectedId = +params.get('id');

      })
    );
  }
```